# How to reduce single session latency in Shiny app for long running database query?

Tags: r, shiny, promise

I have a shiny app where one of the plots is the result of a long running database query. I would like the rest of the application to continue to be responsive and interactive. When the query is completed, I want to update a placeholder graphic with the final result.

I considered using the `promises` package, but that package is designed to keep one session from waiting for work done by another session. As Joe Cheng explains in the [promises tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/promises/articles/shiny.html#the-flush-cycle), the event loop still waits for all outputs to be ready - whether promises or not.

I have successfully rolled my own asynchronous computation in the past using something like this:

```
mydata <- reactiveVal()

output <- renderPlot({ 
  if (isTruthy(mydata())) {
    ggplot(mydata(), ...) 
  } else {
    ggplot(placeholder_or_interim_data_here)
  }
})

observeEvent(input$user_param, {

  stopifnot(0==system2("Rscript", c("myscript.R", input$user_param), wait=FALSE))

})

observe({
  if (script_done) {
    mydata(read_script_result)
  }
  invalidateLater(500)
})
```

For my current project I'm particularly interested in long database queries and don't like the idea of process monitoring and marshaling data around using the file system - which I have to do in my pseudocode above.

I can see how the `future` package would make this a little easier. Is that the right approach? Ideally I wish there were an async reactive - perhaps that returned NULL at first and then returned an updated value later.

Are there other strategies out there for this sort of problem? This seems like it would be a common performance issue?